# T-SQL to generate expect result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a case in SQL: Source table have three columns: ID, Cate, Type.

With same Cate, Type (A, A-) (B, B-) eliminate each other, and return rows have MAX(Id).

eg:

- With cate = AM0001 : Id = 1,2,3 then Id 1,2 eliminate each other --> keep id =3.
- With cate = AM003: Id= 4,6 , type = B --> keep both.
- With cate = AM005: Id= 7,8,9  row: 7,8 eliminate each other --> keep: Id =9
- With cate = AM0006: Id= 10,11, type = A -->keep both.

[image: I've a table source like picture below]

Expected result:

[image: expect result]

I'm using cursor to resolve it quite hard to resolve. Is there any clue for resolving it in T-SQL

Comment: Please **explain** what you're trying to do - don't just post two screenshots and let us *guess* what it is you're up to....... please read [How do I ask a **good** question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn from it!

Comment: is there your case to exclude first two rows then pull 3 rows then exempt two rows?

Comment: Are the rows that eliminate each other always contiguous? i.e. what if AM001 was A-, A-, A, A? Do Cate groups ever contain different Types? i.e. what if AM003 had A- B C?

Comment: No, it's not continuous, source table have 4 type: A, A- , B and B-.

Comment: If you want continuous just partition by Cate order by Type, Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that I understand the problem:

- you have a number of rows with sections ("Cates") and symbols ("Type");
- if there are any symbols ending in a minus sign then these indicate a row without a minus sign should be removed;
- symbols are never "mixed" per section, i.e. a section can never have "A" and "B-";
- there will always be a row to remove if there is a type with a minus;
- rows should be removed starting with the lowest Id.

Then this should work:

```
DECLARE @data TABLE (
    Id INT,
    Cate VARCHAR(5),
    [Type] VARCHAR(2));
INSERT INTO @data SELECT 1, 'AM001', 'A';
INSERT INTO @data SELECT 2, 'AM001', 'A-';
INSERT INTO @data SELECT 3, 'AM001', 'A';
INSERT INTO @data SELECT 4, 'AM003', 'B';
INSERT INTO @data SELECT 6, 'AM003', 'B';
INSERT INTO @data SELECT 7, 'AM005', 'B';
INSERT INTO @data SELECT 8, 'AM005', 'B-';
INSERT INTO @data SELECT 9, 'AM005', 'B';
INSERT INTO @data SELECT 10, 'AM006', 'A';
INSERT INTO @data SELECT 11, 'AM006', 'A';
INSERT INTO @data SELECT 12, 'AM011', 'B';
INSERT INTO @data SELECT 13, 'AM011', 'B-';
INSERT INTO @data SELECT 14, 'AM011', 'B';
WITH NumberToRemove AS (
    SELECT
        Cate,
        COUNT(*) AS TakeOff
    FROM
        @data
    WHERE
        [Type] LIKE '_-'
    GROUP BY
        Cate),
Ordered AS (
    SELECT
        Id,
        Cate,
        [Type],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Cate ORDER BY Id) AS RowId
    FROM
        @data
    WHERE
        [Type] NOT LIKE '_-')
SELECT
    d.*
FROM
    @data d
    LEFT JOIN NumberToRemove m ON m.Cate = d.Cate
    INNER JOIN Ordered o ON o.Id = d.Id
WHERE
    o.RowId > ISNULL(m.TakeOff, 0);
```

The query works by first counting the number of rows to remove from each section ("Cate") by tallying up the number of symbols with a minus sign per section.  Next it sorts the rows where the symbols don't have a minus sign and assigns each row a number in Id order ("row number"), starting back at 1 for each new section ("Cate").

Finally I just pick the rows without a minus sign symbol, where the row number is greater than the number that were to be removed.  Note that if a section has no rows to remove then it will return NULL rows to remove, so I transform this to 0, because ALL rows in that section with have a row number greater than 0.

My results were:

```
Id  Cate    Type
3   AM001   A
4   AM003   B
6   AM003   B
9   AM005   B
10  AM006   A
11  AM006   A
14  AM011   B
```

If my assumptions were incorrect then this script could easily be amended to suit...